# Testing primary task

Tags: vba, excel, testing

I would like to solve the following testing problem. If there is an error i.e. (=1/0) in a cell, the additional tests will not run after that. I would like to know how to solve this issue in the testing primary task part.

```
Private Sub ts_NoBlank(TsCn, STST, LsSt, LsIn, TsRw, MsCo, MsIC, MsSt)
    Dim TsCl, StRw, LsRw, TsSh

    TsCl = ColNrOfField(TsCn)
    StRw = FsRwOfField(TsCn) + 1
    LsRw = LsRwOfField(TsCn)
    TsSh = SheetOfField(TsCn)

' Setting up Status Updates
    PLcSt = -1 'Starting previous local status is set to -100% to show eitherways
    rws = LsRw - StRw
    'this part has to be copied to whenever showing the status (Value of LcSt has to be added each time by function)
    LcSt = 0
    If LcSt - PLcSt >= LsIn Then
        Call ShowStatus(MsSt & " (" & Application.WorksheetFunction.Text(LcSt, "0%") & ")", ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Calculations Running").Range("Started"), STST + (LsSt - STST) * LcSt)
        PLcSt = LcSt
    End If

' Testing primary task
    ErrNr = 0
    For Rw = StRw To LsRw 'ToDo speed up with fromrow torow
        If Len(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(TsSh).Cells(Rw, TsCl)) = 0 Then
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(TsSh).Cells(Rw, TsCl).Interior.ColorIndex = 46
            ErrNr = ErrNr + 1
        End If

        'Showing Local Status
        LcSt = 0.1 + ((Rw / LsRw) * 0.75)
        If LcSt - PLcSt >= LsIn Then
            Call ShowStatus(MsSt & " (" & Application.WorksheetFunction.Text(LcSt, "0%") & ")", ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Calculations Running").Range("Started"), STST + (LsSt - STST) * LcSt)
            PLcSt = LcSt
        End If

    Next Rw
' Updating Test Results on 'Testing' Page

    TRRg = "test" & TsRw & "_results"
    If ErrNr = 0 Then 'If Results are Positive
      ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Testing").Range(TRRg) = MsCo
      ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Testing").Range(TRRg).Interior.ColorIndex = 51
    Else 'If Errors are found
      ErrMS = NumberizeMessage(MsIC, "SP_textvers", "S_textvers", "P_textvers", ErrNr)
      ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Testing").Range(TRRg) = ErrMS
      ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Testing").Range(TRRg).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    End If

    'Showing Local Status
    LcSt = 0.1
    If LcSt - PLcSt >= LsIn Then
      Call ShowStatus(MsSt & " (" & Application.WorksheetFunction.Text(LcSt, "0%") & ")", ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Calculations Running").Range("Started"), STST + (LsSt - STST) * LcSt)
      PLcSt = LcSt
    End If

    ' Highlighting erroneous cells (if not done during testing)
    If ErrNr > 0 Then

    End If
'Showing Local Status 100%
    LcSt = 1
    If LcSt - PLcSt >= LsIn Then
      Call ShowStatus(MsSt & " (" & Application.WorksheetFunction.Text(LcSt, "0%") & ")", ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Calculations Running").Range("Started"), STST + (LsSt - STST) * LcSt)
      PLcSt = LcSt
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're after. Is your code failing? If so where? Is there an additional task that your code needs to do but you don't know how to do it? You will probably find it valuable to declare types on your `Sub` parameters, and at the very least, it will help us understand something more about your code.

Comment: My code in:
 'Testing primary task
    ErrNr = 0
        For Rw = StRw To LsRw 'ToDo speed up with fromrow torow
            If Len(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(TsSh).Cells(Rw, TsCl)) = 0 Then
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets(TsSh).Cells(Rw, TsCl).Interior.ColorIndex = 46
                ErrNr = ErrNr + 1
            End If

Here it works as it colors the cells if there is a formula which is not accepted, but the rest of the tests are not running after that. I would like to solve this, so if there is a cell with a wrong formula, just I want to mark it, and go on with the next processes.

Comment: Please put question clarifications in the question itself, not in comments. Your question can be edited by clicking the "edit" link.

Answer (score 0):

Since you indicate that the `' Testing primary task` section seems to work, but nothing after that seems to execute, I'd suggest that when you get here:

```
'Showing Local Status
LcSt = 0.1
If LcSt - PLcSt >= LsIn Then
```

this condition is false, so the code is never executed.

Then you get here:

```
' Highlighting erroneous cells (if not done during testing)
If ErrNr > 0 Then

End If
```

and there is no code to execute, no matter the value of `ErrNr`.

Then you get here:

```
'Showing Local Status 100%
LcSt = 1
If LcSt - PLcSt >= LsIn Then
```

and it's still evaluating `False`, so again it never executes.

Have you gone through in the debugger to look at the values and ensure everything is as you expect it to be?